# Establish a Habit Score based on number of months with an action per unique user

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to establish a habit score which indicates +1 for every calendar month with an action and -1 for every calendar month with no action by user. The tricky part to this is I would like to do this per user starting after an indicated date (different for every user). If an action is done twice in the same month, I only want it counted as +1. The below image will help illustrate the logic and desired output.

[image: Desired Output]

I need like the result to appear as a calculated column in a separate table with distinct users (this table is already created, I just need the habit score added).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the smoothest solution but it seems to work on the testdata you've provided.

N.B: I've assumed that there is a calendar dimension table, in my case called 'Calendar'.

First add a calculated column to the 'Activity' table:

```
Year-Month = 
FORMAT([Activity_Date]; "YYYY-MM")
```

Then add the desired calculated column to the 'User' table:

```
Habit = 

var minDate =
CALCULATE(
    MIN('Activity'[Activity_Date]);
    'Activity'[Indicator] <> BLANK()
)

var maxDate = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Activity'[Activity_Date])
)

var calendarActivity = DATEDIFF(minDate; maxDate; MONTH)

var sumAddOne = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Activity'[Year-Month]);
    'Calendar'[Date] >= minDate;
    'Calendar'[Date] <= maxDate
)-1

var sumSubtractOne = calendarActivity-sumAddOne

return
IF(
    minDate <> BLANK();
    sumAddOne-sumSubtractOne;
    BLANK()
)
```

Then I end up with a 'User' table lilke this:

[image: Habit Calculated column]

Comment: the above worked however I've only been able to create it once (I need to create a few that vary slightly). Whenever I try to create it, the "Working on it" screen stays on forever and I end up using up 99% of our team's ram (like 45 gigs). I've narrowed the issue down to the sumAddOne variable. Do you know of another way to write this that may fix the issue?

Also why did you use 'Calendar'[Date] instead of 'Activity'[Activity_Date] in the sumAddOne variable?

Comment: For your first question, I don't have a good answer off the top of my head. I'll have to think about it. 
For your second question, it's an optimisation. Instead of filtering the fact table wich can have milions of rows for one calander year I filter the calender which only has 365 rows for one year. When I've found the X number of rows in the calendar I'm interested in Vertipac "knows" which Y number of rows in the fact table the X rows corresponds to and therefor it doesnt have to itterate over the fact table to first determin wich rows to count.